# Is there a way to shorten the C++11 lambda signature in declaration?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, syntactic-sugar

I want to shorten the following type of lambdas:

```
[] (SomeVeryLongTemplateType<int, float, char, std::string>, AnotherLongType) {};
```

Since the only reason for this lambda is to initialize some class `std::function<...>` member - it doesn't capture anything, it doesn't have argument names, it returns nothing, it does nothing.

If the shortening operation is expressed as a function of the number of arguments in signature, then I want this function to have the complexity O(1).

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for an empty  lambda which does nothing, so that your `std::function` object will always be in callable state!

If so, then use this one which can be reused, *for any number of parameters*:

```
static const struct empty_lambda_t //static and const applies to the object!
{
      template<typename ...T>
      void operator()(T && ... ) const {} //does nothing

}empty_lambda {}; //declare an object which is static and const
```

And then use it as:

```
 std::function<void()>          fun1 = empty_lambda;
 std::function<void(int,int)>   fun2 = empty_lambda;
 std::function<void(whatever)>  fun3 = empty_lambda;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: What use this can be? Could you give me an example where this can be useful? I guess I should ask the OP about this, but nevertheless if you could would be great.

Comment: @bolov: The use is that the function objects (`fun1` for example) can be invoked.  On the other hand, if you declare only this `:std::function<void(int)> fun;` (without any initialization) and then doing `fun(10)` will throw exception, because there is nothing in `fun` to be invoked.

Comment: So it's kind of like an null/default initialization for lambdas.

Comment: @bolov: I don't know what you mean by *"null/default initialization"*. As I said in my answer, it is empty callable entity which does nothing. So if you initialize your std::function with it, then your function object will be in callable state, which means exception will not be thrown if you invoke it. If that is what you meant by *"null/default initialization"*, then yes that it is!

Answer (score 11):

in C++14 there will be "generic lambdas" that should simplify long type names in parameters as I understand:

```
auto lambda = [](auto x, auto y) {return x + y; };
```

here `auto` is like Template type

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Generic_lambdas

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for "polymorphic lambdas". They do not exist (yet), so no.

However, you can make it easier with proper use of `typedef`s, so you don't have to type the entire thing every single time.